# I am adding two check constraints in mysql getting 3813 error

Tags: mysql

```
Create Table returndetails
(
Order_id int ,
Product_id int,
Quantity int not null check(order_details.Quantity>=returndetails.Quantity),
return_date date not null check (orders.order_date-returndetails.return_date>=30),
primary key(Order_id,Product_id),
foreign key (Order_id,Product_id) references order_details(order_id,product_id),
foreign key (order_id) references orders(order_id)
);
```

I am creating a returndetails table so I am taking reference from order_details(that means i can return an item only if that order_id and product_id is in order_details table ) also order_date is in orders table ,
I can return an item only before 30 days from the order_date.

When I am adding the date constraint I am getting the following error 
What to do???

```
Create Table returndetails ( Order_id int , Product_id int, Quantity int not null check(order_details.Quantity>=returndetails.Quantity), return_date date not null check (orders.order_date-returndetails.return_date>=30), primary key(Order_id,Product_id), foreign key (Order_id,Product_id) references order_details(order_id,product_id), foreign key (order_id) references orders(order_id) )
```

> Error Code: 3813. Column check constraint 'returndetails_chk_2'
>   references other column.

Comment: CHECK constraint cannot refer to another record or another table - it may refer to the fields values of checked record only. [CHECK Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).

Comment: You can use triggers on BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE for prevent to store wrong values